# Where does the extra money come from for 2x,3x..etc. ETF

Tags: etf, leveraged

There are leveraged ETFs' that track for example the S&P 500. My question is where does it generate the extra money? If for example a 2x leveraged ETF tracking the S&P500 receives 10 million Dollars from investors, and one day the S&P500 rises 10%, where is the leveraged ETF going to get the extra 2 million dollars (since it rises 20% due to 2x)? Does the leveraged ETF even own the underlying shares or does it just "track" the S&P500?

On another note, if it doesn't own any shares but just does tracking, how do we know the company didn't secretly tweak the algorithm to steal some minute percentage for itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities (not the only ones)

- They borrow another 10 Million to buy twice as many securities compared to a non-leveraged ETF
- They use derivatives like options or swaps to obtain twice the exposure to the underlying index.

Note that these leveraged ETFs promise to return a multiple of the *daily* returns, and must often "rebalance" to get back to the leveraged exposure, which may mean that the returns over multiple days is not the same multiple that they promise daily. Borrowing costs money, and options do not change in value exactly linearly.  That's one reason that they are not good for long term investing. When things are good, leveraged ETFs are good, but when things go bad, leveraged ETFs are much worse.

> On another note, if it doesn't own any shares but just does tracking, how do we know the company didn't secretly tweak the algorithm to steal some minute percentage for itself?

That's not how funds or ETFs work. There must be securities owned by the ETF that determine its value. They don't just "make up" a value based on some promise.

Comment: Maybe they could pair the ETF with a short ETF? Although I think if they did that, they'd have to have creation/redemption of the two ETFs be in tandem.

Comment: "There must be securities owned by the ETF that determine its value." To expand on that, there have to be securities that are bought to create shares, and that shares can then redeemed for. The market value is maintained by this capability of exchange; arbitrage keeps the value of the ETF within a small range of the value of the underlyings. If there were no securities that an ETF could be exchanged for, then it would just be a pyramid scheme.